# git commit failed cannot run gpg2

Tags: git, commit

I'm trying to commit my files through terminal because there is more than 100files.

When im trying to commit my files i get this error message.

[Click for photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mt2o3.png)

I have tried to redo everything from the beginning,made a new file, made it as git repo,etc.. but at the end it is the same as before.

I have tried to install gpg,gpg2,gnupg,gnupg2 but nothing helped.

Anyone know whats wrong ?

Comment: As a workaround you could (temporarily) disable commit signature probably.

Comment: Or maybe you have hooks that do something special? I'd try to find out which command is running on commit and make it work alone. How did you install gpg?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using mac and gpg2 is installed you can try this

```
git config --global gpg.program $(which gpg2)
```

Ref: https://docs.github.com/en/github/authenticating-to-github/managing-commit-signature-verification/telling-git-about-your-signing-key